# Identifying blobs in image as that of a vehicle

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, blob, simplecv

Any idea how I can get the smaller blobs belonging to the same vehicle count as 1 vehicle? Due to background subtraction, in the foreground mask, some of the blobs belonging to a vehicle are quite small, and hence filtering the blobs based on their size won't work.

Comment: How about using a mask controlled watershed transformation ? An image would help in such cases. And also describing why the over-segmentation is a good starting point.

Comment: I am unable to upload images here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filtering things based on `colorDistance()` and the comparing the mean color of the blobs in the image with the vehicle against a control image of the background without the car in it.  The SimpleCV docs have a tutorial specifically on [this topic](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/parking.html).  That said... [it may not always work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600641/simplecv-car-detection-example).  Another possibility (just occurred to me) might be summing up the area of the blobs of interest and seeing if that sum is over a given thresh-hold, rather than just any one blob itself.

Comment: Will colorDistance() work? As am using the fore ground mask to detect blobs, won't all the blobs detected be of the same color, i.e. white?

Comment: Are you working with a Kinect or other 'depth' camera?  My impression from the book and tutorials that was the intended use of the foreground mask.  Not sure how you'd tell one object in the foreground from another without something like colorDistance().  Take a look at the docs I linked earlier and see if that works for you.

Comment: No. I am working with regular video of traffic. The background subtraction method is to differentiate the background from objects in motion. The objects in motion are then represented as white "blobs" in the foreground mask.

Comment: What about filtering those blob based on certain values, i.e. blob must be bigger than 'nnn' pixels in area?  That should eliminate some of the noise from the bits-n-pieces, but may have to be determined empirically how high or low to set the thresh-hold values.